# software that list previously installed programs

Tags: window

Is there a software that can detect and list previously installed programs on a  computer?
Or any method you know which I can use so that I could see what programs were previously installed assuming that those programs were only uninstalled using the add/remove programs in control panel.
Or if you know a method which will also detect and list previously installed programs which are uninstalled using advanced uninstaller like revo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Windows event log. [Here](http://desktopengineer.com/windowsinstallereventlogmessages) are the events to look for.

> 11728 Product [2] -- Configuration completed successfully.    Informational message that configuration of the product was successful.

Comment: If the logs were not deleted..